# Creating a morph in metaball like animation

Tags: animation, metaballs

Is there a way to create an animation like this one:

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello, have you tried to fill a shape with som fluids?

Comment: i would try it maybe with a volumetric shader - with noise and a "fading".

Comment: I saw this with the new geometry nodes: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keKDABQfxQU and I think I can just edit the nodes to get a more smooth and metaball like effect

Comment: actually that's a good idea!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not had much luck with Geometry Nodes, so far.. open to correction, but I think the resolution would have to be insanely high to get the smooth blobby character. Maybe someone else will come up with a geometry solution.

Here's a basic volumetric shader option, I'm sure it can be improved:

[image]

- Quite a regular 3D *Voronoi Cell* distribution, distorted by *Noise* on its texture-space.
- Put through a threshold, to make a definite boundary between solid and empty
- The threshold is an animated mapping of the texture-space X, to make a wipe.

[image]

Here, I've cheated, filling dark shadows with a bit of emission.. the lighting on your reference is more sophisticated.

[image]

Comment: Looks great! thanks

Comment: yeah I got a close enough with the link I provided but the cracks from cell fracture are clear unless the shading is flat, this is closer to the original!

Comment: @Andrew Thanks! Still needs work...  it's one of those that can be tweaked for ever :)